# Spring Boot OAuth Ressource Server Proxy Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-reactive

I am currently struggeling using a proxy in combination with Spring-Webflux. In other services I always followed this approach, which worked perfectly (proxy configuration is retrieved from standard environment variables):

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().build();
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client));
    return restTemplate;
  }
```

But now I am trying to setup an OAuth-Ressource-Server using the Spring Oauth-Resource-Server package. This package uses the Spring-Webflux for HTTP(S). The service now tries to fetch the jwk-set from the given uri (proxy needed) and fails because of a connection refused error. Did anyone get a combination of Spring-Webflux/OAuth-Ressource and proxy working?

Answer (score 4):

Found out by myself that providing a NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder bean with a correctly configured webclient solves the problem.

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;
import reactor.netty.tcp.ProxyProvider;

@Data
@Component
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "proxy")
public class ProxyConfig {

  private String host;
  private int port;
  private String username;
  private String password;

  @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
  private String jwkSetUri;

  @Bean
  public WebClient webClient(ReactorClientHttpConnector reactorClientHttpConnector) {
    return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(reactorClientHttpConnector).build();
  }

  @Bean
  public HttpClient httpClient() {
    return HttpClient.create()
        .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient ->
            tcpClient.proxy(
                proxy -> proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP).host(host)
                    .port(port).username(username)
                    .password(s -> password)));
  }

  @Bean
  ReactorClientHttpConnector reactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient httpClient) {
    return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
  }

  @Bean
  public NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder nimbusReactiveJwtDecoder(WebClient webClient) {
    return NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder
        .withJwkSetUri(jwkSetUri)
        .webClient(webClient).build();
  }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to make create an instance of a `NimbusJwtDecoder`, but after reading your post realized I needed to be creating a `NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder`. Being new to reactive/Reactor, it is the simple things like this that have hung me up. Thank you for your answer.